Can we use HoloLens 2 research mode functions in unity editor for play mode?
When I use Holographic Remoting in Unity play mode，the background of the Game window is black, I want it to be the scenes that the camera captured. Is this possible?
I'm new to develop HoloLens 2 app and lack of experience.

Research Mode can’t be used in Unity Editor. To learn how to enable Research Mode, please refer to HoloLens Research Mode - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn.
